# Plugin [id: 'io.qameta.allure', version: '2.8.1'] was not found in any of the following sources: while generating Allure Report

Tags: java, gradle, allure

I am trying to generate Allure Report in a gradle based project. Please help me to understand the root cause of this error.

Here is the main code snippets from the build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'io.qameta.allure' version '2.8.1'
    }

def allureVersion = '2.14.0'

repositories {
    // Use Maven Central for resolving dependencies.
    mavenCentral()
}

allure {
    version = allureVersion
    autoconfigure = false
    aspectjweaver = true
}
 
/* Module specific dependencies */
dependencies {
    //Junit5
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.7.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.2'
    // Allure
    implementation 'io.qameta.allure:allure-junit5:2.14.0'
    runtimeOnly 'org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.9.7'
```

Gradle Version - 7.3.3, Using SDK - Amazon Corretto Version 17 (Java)

I have tried different version of allure report and plug in. But could not understand what is causing this issue.

Below error comes in Intellij

```
 Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'io.qameta.allure', version: '2.8.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'io.qameta.allure:io.qameta.allure.gradle.plugin:2.8.1')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
    Google
    MavenRepo
```

Comment: Please use text instead of images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question for more details on the reason.

Comment: Updated the text instead of image, thank you for sharing the guideline.

Comment: @TheSociety I am also facing the same issue. Did you get a solution for the above issue?